# Do mathematicians visualise what 4D would look like when they are working with abstract 4D concepts?

Tags: geometry, soft-question, dimension-theory-analysis

I was wondering if mathematicians do truly have a sense of visualising what the fourth dimension would look like in general, such as the fourth dimension as found in hypercubes. I know that we, as 3D beings, cannot literally perceive 4D objects just as 2D objects can have no literal image of a 3D object. However, I do know that we can give the 2D objects a sense of whatvisualising 3D objects would look like if we introduce some abstract concepts, such as stereographical graphing, to them. So, my question is whether mathematicians have a rough concept of the visualisation of their work when they work with abstract concepts - in geometry - that involve dealing with the fourth dimension? And, I was also wondering if it would be useful to attempt to have an intuitive sense of 4D objects and planes before truly working with concepts involving the fourth dimension, because I fear I may end up like a machine lacking any fundamental intuition of their work and the concepts of their work which would truly irritate me as I always try proving concepts, intuitively understanding them, playing with them and even developing them further into more abstract concepts before I actually work the concept in problems.

Comment: Some do, some don't. Famously Fields Medal winner Edward Witten can.

Comment: You can succeed in research without being able to visualize what you are studying. Pontryagin was blind for most of his life.

Comment: Does that prove him as having a greater intuition of perhaps the geometry of 4D objects, albeit most mathematicians would know the formal logic behind the geometry of 4D objects and their properties. So, does his visualisation bring an aid and intuition into solving, say, topological problems in 4D objects?

Comment: If you're asking about Witten yes. One of his more famous topological results was reportedly figured out in his head visualizing moves before he figured out how to formalize that. But don't let that discourage you.